# I need move photo left and right using onclick event

Tags: javascript

```
let left = document.querySelector('#left');
let right = document.querySelector('#right');
let counter = 1;
let img_contant = document.querySelector('.img_contant');
let size = img_contant.clientWidth;

let increment = function () {
  img_contant.style = `margin-left: ` + counter * size +  `px`;
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
}

let decrement = function () {
  img_contant.style = `margin-left: ` + counter * size + `px`;
  counter--;
  console.log(counter);  
}

left.addEventListener('click', decrement);

right.addEventListener('click', increment);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you use code blocks and provide your HTML code pls? It would be helpfull to understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style attributes are converted from dash-case to camelCase for the style property.

img_contant.style.marginLeft = counter * size + 'px';

Answer (score 0):

In your increment and decrement code, you are not using the `style.marginLeft` property which is intended. check the below code

```js
let left = document.querySelector('#left');

let right = document.querySelector('#right');

let counter = 0;

let img_contant = document.querySelector('.img_contant');

let size = img_contant.clientWidth;

const increment = function () {
  counter++;
  img_contant.style.marginLeft = `${counter * size}px`;   
 }

const decrement = function () {
  counter--;
  img_contant.style.marginLeft = `${counter * size}px`;
 }

left.addEventListener('click', decrement);

right.addEventListener('click', increment);
```

```html
<button id="left"> Left </button>
<button id="right"> Right </button>
<div>
<img class="img_contant" src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1000459/2436/i/450/depositphotos_24366251-stock-photo-soccer-ball.jpg" height = 200 width = 200 />
</div>
```